# cache failed ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 and I tried to update via terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Everything seemed to be running normally and is still running I just cant get anything from the software center and at the end of the update process it displayed this

```
Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_main_binary-i386_Packages
```

And whenever I try to install anything from the software center it says something is wrong with the cache or something like that...

How can I be able to install software from USC

Comment: Are you connected to the internet, try opening your browser. then if everything is well try sudo ap-get install -f .And then open software center and install apps

Comment: Are you sure that the line you put in the question was the full line? Can you retry and check?

Comment: yes i am, actually i am using it now, and i ran that this is the result "kobey@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded."

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to solve your problem.

Open Terminal and run the following commands.

```
 $ wget https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8850924/fixpackage
```

Then give permission to the script

```
$ chmod +x ./fixpackage
```

Now run the script

```
$ sudo ./fixpackage
```

Wait for updates to be completed and errors fixed.

[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/239145)

The commands in the script are:

```
sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

so either you can run the script or just run these commands

Comment: i ran all of that and it didnt help at all, it says          Package dependencies cannot be resolved                            This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.